# Geometric Generalized Linear Model

Tags: self-study, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model

I'm practicing for a Statistical Models test I have tomorrow, most of it is going well but I'm having issues with the Generalized Linear Model portion of the course. Here is the situation. We have $n$ independent observations which we assume to be geometric, the parameter $\pi_i$ depends on three covariates, let's call them $A$, $B$, and $C$. This gives us the following:

$Z_i \sim Geom(\pi_i)$

$P(Z_i=k)=\pi_i(1-\pi_i)^k$

$\eta_i=x_{iA}\beta_1+x_{iB}\beta_2+x_{iC}\beta_3=g(\pi_i)$

I need to show that this density function is part of the exponential family with the following properties:

$f(y,\theta_i)=exp\{\frac{y\theta_i-b(\theta_i)}{\phi/A_i}+c(y,\phi/A_i)\}$

I start by transforming $P(Z_i=k)$:

$P(Z_i=k)=\pi_i(1-\pi_i)^k=exp\{ln(\pi_i(1-\pi_i)^k)\}=e^{ln(\pi_i)+k\cdot ln(1-\pi_i)}$

Since $\pi_i \in (0,1)$ we need $g(\pi_i)$ to map from $(0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which in turn means $g^{-1}(\theta_i)$ maps from $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow(0,1)$

An option would be to use the logit link function, correct? Since we are trying to estimate probabilities. That would mean we get:

$\theta_i=g(\pi_i)=ln(\frac{\pi_i}{1-\pi_i})$

From this follows: $\pi_i=\frac{e^{\theta_i}}{1+e^{\theta_i}}=\frac{1}{1+e^{-\theta_i}}$

If I plug either into the transformed density function I keep ending up with a term $k\cdot ln(1+e^{\theta_i})$ while the $f(y,\theta_i)$ should have $k\cdot \theta_i$ or $k\cdot ln({e^{\theta_i}})$

I feel like I'm doing something wrong, all the literature suggests this link function but I cannot get it to fit to the exponential family. Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your derivations are correct up to the point when you try to insist on using the logit function as the canonical link. Don't impose a functional form on $\theta_i$, let the distribution guide you. How should $\theta_i$ be defined so that $k\theta_i$ shows up in the exponent? You already figured out that $\theta_i=\ln(\pi_i/(1-\pi_i))$ won't work.

**Note**

While this answers your direct question, I just realized that you will have further difficulties while trying to link in covariates. The reason is that your  parametrization is not particularly useful for modeling, since $p$ is not the expected value. You might want to reparametrize your model with the distribution mean before linking it to covariates.

Comment: So that would be $\theta_i=ln(1-\pi_i)$ then? $\pi_i=1-e^{e^{\theta_i}}$ would give that result. But doesn't that give a problem in the $e^{ln(\pi_i)}$ part? Or since you can cancel these that doesn't matter? Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, that's the right choice, though I think you messed up the solution for $\pi_i$. The rest of the terms don't have $k$, so they will wind up in the other undefined functions.